# Recursive Json node update

Tags: java, json, gson, jsonnode

I have a code where this help me to update the JSON node values. But, there is a small complexity in my way of handling. I have a Node that may come across any JSONObject.

Note: Below is the sample json structure.

```
{              
    "Apple": {
        "Name": "AA",
        "description": "apple"
    },           
    "Mango": {
        "Name": "RA",
        "description": "Mango"
    }
}
```

I would like to update the Name and Description for both Apple and Mango.

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: I would like to update name and description for both apple and mango. How can I do that.. I am from Testing , so I am my not be able to describe it development terms.. sorry about that...

Answer (score 2):

Before:

```
{
   "Apple":{
      "Name":"AA",
      "description":"apple"
   },
   "Mango":{
      "Name":"RA",
      "description":"Mango"
   }
}
```

With this code:

```
JsonObject Apple = myJson.getAsJsonObject("Apple");
Apple.addProperty("Name", "BB");
Apple.addProperty("description", "New apple");
```

You will get:

```
{
   "Apple":{
      "Name":"BB",
      "description":"New apple"
   },
   "Mango":{
      "Name":"RA",
      "description":"Mango"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the put method: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
JSONObject apple =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("apple");
person.put("Name", "Honeycrisp");

//Similarly
JSONObject apple =  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("apple");
person.put("description", "a sweet apple");
```

Comment: Thank you. But  would like to see in java. I am working on creating a API framework. I will be given with request json and I would need to run with different values. I could find few solutions in stack overflow to update json using recursive function but when it comes to above scenario like updating description or name for different object, I am stuck .

Comment: @Danesh I have updated my answer with the Java solution, sorry about that!